# Array resizing using reference / pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I made a small code to resize a dynamic array, passing pointer X as a reference.

```
void resize(int*& X , int & dimX){
int * new_X = new int [dimX+20];
 for(int i=0;i<dimX;i++)
    new_X[i] = X[i];
 delete [] X;
 X = new_X;
 dimX += 20;
}
```

My doubt is: what would be the difference in the code if i decided to pass the array X as a sole pointer? 
For example:

```
void resize(int* X , int & dimX)
```

Is that even possible for this kind of operation? (resizing). Thanks a lot and sorry for the dumb question, i'm a beginner.

Comment: Raw arrays are not "dynamic" (as you can see with the work you need to do!). Use `std::vector` or `std::list` if you need a "dynamic" collection.

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks for info :) i know about the vector class, but i just need to do a resize function by myself, and what i was wondering is: what's the best way to pass the array X to the function? and how passing int * X instead of int *&x would affect the code.

Comment: To modify a something which is passed as argument to a function  you need to pass its reference or a pointer to that thing. So if you want to modify a pointer, you need to pass a reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `X` as an `int*`, then you are passing a copy of the pointer. This means if you change `X` on the line `X = new_X;`, you will only update the copy, not the original.

You can either keep using a reference to the pointer like you are currently doing, or take `X` as an `int*` but return `new_X` and have the caller use the returned value.